# How do I replace a value in a matrix which corresponding to another matrix?

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, if-statement, replace

For example

```
a = ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6']
b = [[(1, 0.5), (2, 0.8)], [(4, 0.11), (6, 0.23)]]
```

And I want to get a matrix c:

```
c = [0.5, 0.8, 0, 0.11, 0, 0]
```

That's like if the i in a = ww for ww,ee in n for n in b, then replace  with ee else 0

I try some if and else command and here is my code

```
for n in b:
for t,y in n:
    for tt in a:
        mmm = [y if t == ''.join(tt) else ''.join(tt)]
        print(mmm)
```

But it failed. How should I code for this situation?

Comment: Shouldn't the last value in `c` be `0.23` ?

Comment: `[dict(sum(b,[])).get(int(i),0) for i in a]`

Answer (score 1):

#### [`chain`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain.from_iterable) + [`dict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict) + list comprehension

Your `b` mapping is a list of lists, you can flatten this into an iterable of tuples via `chain.from_iterable`. Then feed to `dict` to create an efficient mapping.

Finally, use a list comprehension with `dict.get` for the desired result. Just remember to convert the values of `a` from `str` to `int`.

```
from itertools import chain

a = ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6']
b = [[(1, 0.5), (2, 0.8)], [(4, 0.11), (6, 0.23)]]

b_dict = dict(chain.from_iterable(b))
c = [b_dict.get(i, 0) for i in map(int, a)]

print(c)

[0.5, 0.8, 0, 0.11, 0, 0.23]
```

Answer (score 0):

This iterates through list `a` comparing it's value with first value of tuples in `b` list. This appends the second value of tuple to output list if the first value of tuple matches with the value in `a`:

```
from itertools import chain

a = ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6']
b = [[(1, 0.5), (2, 0.8)], [(4, 0.11), (6, 0.23)]]

b = list(chain.from_iterable(b))
lst = []
for x in a:
    for y, z in b:
        if y == int(x):
            lst.append(z)
            break
    else:
        lst.append(0)

print(lst)
# [0.5, 0.8, 0, 0.11, 0, 0.23]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can convert your double-list of mappings into a lookup dictionary and use a list-comp:

```
a = ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6']
b = [[(1, 0.5), (2, 0.8)], [(4, 0.11), (6, 0.23)]]

# convert b to a dictionary:
d = {str(k):v for tup in b for k,v in tup} # stringify the lookup key value 
print(d)

# apply the lookup to a's values
result = [d.get(k,0) for k in a]
print(result)
```

Output:

```
# the lookup-dictionary
{'1': 0.5, '2': 0.8, '4': 0.11, '6': 0.23}

# result of list c,omprehension
[0.5, 0.8, 0, 0.11, 0, 0.23]
```

Related:

- [dict.get(key[, default])](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.get)
- [Why dict.get(key) instead of dict[key]?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11041405/why-dict-getkey-instead-of-dictkey)